# 2007 Vauxhall Zafira has ABS light on, then speedo failed and battery draining

Tags: abs, battery-drain, speedometer

I have a strange problem on a 2007 Vauxhall Zafira.

We went on holiday for 2 weeks and when we came back we started the car and the ABS light on the speedo was lit.

After a few days the speedo died and the battery seems to be draining as I fully charged it a week ago and it is already hard to start.

Not sure what it is but it seems to possibly be electrical and the missus is worried as she can't afford a hefty bill to fix it, which the garage has banded about.

Any insight would really be appreciated.

Comment: could be the alternator fuse is blown, some cars has part of the electrical load on the alternator side so if the fuse blows it stop charging and those systems stop. the battery will drain once you start the car

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Much appreciated and i will look into.

Answer (score 1):

So...i tested with a multi-meter and found a drain which was associated to a bad fuse for the ABS system. However, the fuse was changed [by garage] and it didn't fix the issue and the speedometer unit had to be removed to be sent off for a fix. The wheel bearing ABS/speedometer unit was OK so nothing to do with that.
Unfortunately the complete 'fix' is costing £500 but in all honesty not sure how much of the actual fix is not something simple that i am paying through the nose for unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

All the symptoms *could* be explained by a draining battery, and the key is to understand *why* the battery is draining.

If the car is still on it's original battery it could simply be that the battery itself is no longer holding charge properly, for a 2007 car that would make it ~ 10 years old which depending on the use it's experienced during it's life could mean it's simply reaching end of life. A decent garage should be able to test the battery for you or you could rule it out by replacing it since they are unlikely to be massively expensive for something like a Zafira

If the battery itself is fine then there could well be something draining it - these can be an utter nightmare to track down as a it can be anything from a short in the wiring loom to a malfunctioning bit of electronics to a poor grounding point. Check the usual suspects out first - make sure you haven't knocked any of the interior lights to an "always on" setting, if your 12v sockets are "always live" make sure nothing has been left plugged in, that sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Much appreciated. I will do a mutlimeter test on the battery and see what i get. Would be great if it was a battery issue only.